# How to paginate an array of results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

This function can paginate an array of items:

```
function paginate(res,page,page_size,max_page_size) {
        page=page||1;
        page_size=page_size||10;
        max_page_size=max_page_size||100;
        page_size=page_size>max_page_size?max_page_size:page_size;
        var pages=Math.round( res.length / page_size),
            items=[];
        for( var p=1; p <= pages; p++) {
            var start= Math.round( page_size * (p-1) );
            items.push( res.slice(start,start+page_size) );
        }
        return page < items.length?items[page-1]:items[ items.length-1 ];
    }
```

having

- res = array
- page = current page
- page_size = number of items to be returned in a page
- max_page_size = max number of items for page

```js
function paginate(res, page, page_size, max_page_size) {
  page = page || 1;
  page_size = page_size || 10;
  max_page_size = max_page_size || 100;
  page_size = page_size > max_page_size ? max_page_size : page_size;
  var pages = Math.round(res.length / page_size),
    items = [];
  for (var p = 1; p <= pages; p++) {
    var start = Math.round(page_size * (p - 1));
    items.push(res.slice(start, start + page_size));
  }
  return page < items.length ? items[page - 1] : items[items.length - 1];
}

var list = Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function() {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 3))).map(function() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (123 - 97) + 97));
  }).join('')
});

console.log(list)
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
  console.log("page", i, paginate(list, i, 2, 2))
}
```

This function has a bug, since as soon as it reaches the last paginated result, it returns always the same page. Why? Is there an alternative solution?

**[UPDATE]**

The issue was in the indexes calculation, this is the right version:

```
 function paginate(res,page,page_size,max_page_size) {
    page=page||1;
    page_size=page_size||10;
    max_page_size=max_page_size||100;
    page_size=page_size>max_page_size?max_page_size:page_size;
    var pages=Math.ceil( res.length / page_size),
        items=[];
    for( var p=1; p <= pages; p++) {
        var start= page_size * (p-1)
        items.push( res.slice(start,start+page_size) );
    }
    return page <= items.length?items[page-1]:[];
}
```

There were 2 errors: `Math.round` instead of `Math.ceil` and the last ternary operator `page <= items.length?items[page-1]:[];`

Comment: Are you referring to your last for-loop? The `console.log("page", i, paginate(list, i, 2, 2))`?

Comment: @Matt if you see the index max value was set to `8` with `2` results for page, so you can see that, starting from the fifth element (we have 10 elements in the list), all the other three results are the same in the page.

Comment: Change `for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) ` to `for (var i = 1; i <= list.length/2; i++)`

Comment: @matt nope the problem is in the function, try like `console.log(paginate(list, 5, 2, 2))` and  `console.log(paginate(list, 6, 2, 2))`, you will get always the same values.

Comment: Your return is told to give you back the last index of `items` for anything larger than `items.length` which is 5. If you ask for page 5+, it will give you the last page which is 5 ( `items[4]`). What are you expecting to return for `paginate(list, 6, 2, 2)`?

Comment: @Matt supposed that we are rendering a page filled with those results, `paginate(list, 6, 2, 2)`  in this case, should just return the same results of `paginate(list, 5, 2, 2)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't identified the exact issue with your code yet, but I remember struggling alot with keeping state and resetting the index when I reached the end of the array while using rounding functions.

In the end I just made a 'chunker' to divide an array into chunks and hooked that up to something that rendered the array contents using the previous() and next() methods to grab the correct art of the array. Which page it actualy represents in the view, is up to the view to cache.

```
var Chunker = function Chunker( config ) {
        if ( !Array.isArray( config.data ) ) {
            throw new Error('chunker source is not an array');
            return false;
        }
        this.data = config.data;
        this.index = 0;
        this.length = config.len || config.data.length; // Amount of items per chunk. When not defined, will return the entire array.
    };
Chunker.prototype = {
    'constructor' : Chunker,
    'index' : function index( number ) { // => current index (getter) || => this (setter)
        if ( number !== undefined ) {
            this.index = index;
            return this;
        }
        else return this.index;
    },
    'current' : function current() { // => { "index", "data" }
        return {
            "index" : this.index,
            "data" : this.data.slice( this.index, this.index + this.length )
        };
    },
    'next' : function next() { // => next chunk
        this.index += this.length;
        if ( this.index > this.data.length ) this.index = this.data.length - (this.data.length % this.length);
        return this.current();
    },
    'previous' : function previous() { // => previous chunk
        this.index -= this.length;
        if (this.index < 0 ) this.index = 0;
        return this.current();
    },
    'reset' : function reset() { // => this
        this.index(0);
        return this;
    }
};
```